# Sumar 1 a año actual con función HOY()

Tags: excel, funciones, date, formato

Tengo la celda B3 configurada con formato fecha y la tabla de la siguiente forma

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero hacer es que, teniendo como formato de celda como fecha, si el mes en la celda a A2 es ENERO, B2 muestre 2023 (es decir que sume 1 al año actual, pero en su lugar devuelve 14/1/1900 y no sé cómo corregirlo ¿Qué puedo hacer?
Tengo la siguiente fórmula:

```
=SI(A2="ENERO";TEXTO(HOY();"yyyy")+1;TEXTO(HOY();"yyyy"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás muy cerca:

```
=SI(MES(A2)=1;TEXTO(HOY();"yyyy")+1;TEXTO(HOY();"yyyy")+0)
```

Para evitar que la función MES() retorne valores del tipo 14/1/1900, recuerda darle formato General o Número a la celda, pues el retorno de la función MES() es un número y si lo representas como Fecha vas a tener los inconvenientes que mencionas.

[image: Excel mostrar año + 1 si el mes es ENERO]

Comment: Gracias, pero yo quiero que la celda quede configurada como fecha.

Comment: Eso no va a ser posible, pues para Excel 2022, 2023, por ejemplo, no son fechas válidas, les faltan el día y el mes. Como máximo puedes poner un formato personalizado y colocar yyyy en el tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Está esta fórmula (Configurada la celda con formato fecha)

```
=SI(A2="ENERO";TEXTO(HOY()+365;"yyyy");TEXTO(HOY();"yyyy"))
```

La función `HOY()` devuelve la fecha actual, para cambiar de año hay que sumarle 365 días que es la cantidad de días que tiene un año.